# vba average calculator userform

Tags: vba, excel, userform

Hey im trying to write a small VBA program that calculates the average quiz score the problem is when i enter in the third number it comes back incorrect after doing the first two right.What am i missing?

This is the design view
[image: This is the design view]

```
Option Explicit

Dim total As Double
Dim number As Double
Dim average As Double


Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

If IsNumeric(TextBox1.Value) = True Then
    total = CDbl(average + TextBox1.Value)
    number = CDbl(number + 1)
    average = CDbl(total / number)
    TextBox2.Value = number
    TextBox3.Value = average
    TextBox1.Value = ""    
Else
    MsgBox ("please enter a number")
    TextBox1.Value = ""
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the value of `number` ? make sure it isn't `0`

Comment: Number is the number of times a score is entered it ticks up every time i enter a score.Its what im dividing the total by

Comment: I understood that part, what is the value the first time ? is it `0` ? because then you are dividing be zero and getting an error

Comment: Do yourself (and others) a favor, and rename your controls, before you start adding logic. Names like `TextBox1` doesn't exactly make it easy to read your code (and hence help you find mistakes in it). Better naming could be something like `txtAverage`, `txtTimesTaken` and `txtQuizScore`.

Comment: Will do Sorry just starting VBA

Comment: No problem. It´s a common mistake. But keep in mind, that the readibility of your code, is almost as important as its functionality. Afterall, you rarely write some code, which you never re-visit :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your math is off. If you want to do it, using the previous average, and the new value, then the formula you should use is this:

```
( [old average] + ( [new value] / [count - 1] ) ) / ( [count] / [count - 1] )
```

However, as you might see, this is not a very easy-to-read design. I would go for a design, using an [array](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vba/vba_arrays.htm). That way you can keep the math a lot more intuitive, plus you can look back at old score, if you want. The easiest design is probably to keep the array the size of your score count. This requires `redim()` each time you add a new score. From a performance point-of-view, this is quite bad practice. But in your tiny calculator, thats hardly going to be a problem.

Comment: Sorry for being dumb but could you explain that math like im 5?

Comment: You said it works for the first two values. If they are 5 and 3 then the average is 4. Which is correct. If you then add 7, the average should be `(5 + 3 + 7) / 3 = 5`. But using your method, you would get, `(4 + 7) / 3 = 3.7`. Which is not correct. the math I showed there is a work around, but not a very pretty one. Hence, you should use arrays :-).

Comment: ok ill learn arrays another day .wow thank you for pointing this out for me i just realised total = CDbl(total + Quizscore) .makes it functional even if its not pretty.Instead of  total = CDbl(average + Quizscore)

Comment: The very short explanation of what I did, is that I took into consideration, that the new value should have a "weight" proportional to the number of samples. I.e. if you already have 100 previous quiz scores, then a new once should only affect the average very slightly. By dividing the new score with the count minus one, it will have less effect on the average, if there are already a lot of samples. Hope that makes a little sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should get number, average, and total value before you do the calculations:

```
Option Explicit

Dim total As Double
Dim number As Double
Dim average As Double


Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

number = 0
average = 0
total = 0

If IsNumeric(TextBox1.Value) = True Then
    total = CDbl(average + TextBox1.Value)
    number = CDbl(number + 1)
    'prevent error
    If number > 0 then
        average = CDbl(total / number)
    Else
        average = 0
    End If
    TextBox2.Value = number
    TextBox3.Value = average
    TextBox1.Value = ""    
Else
    MsgBox ("please enter a number")
    TextBox1.Value = ""
End If

End Sub
```

Hope this help.